# FB suspended app account, how can i submit a review without uploading app on appstore?

Tags: ios, flutter, facebook, oauth-2.0, social-media

need expert advice here: An app is using FB auth for login. Its FB account is suspended by FB due to their terms violation. However, I have fixed the issue but app is not yet release on Appstore and Playstore yet.
I have filed an appeal at developer portal with screenshots and required information of my implemented fixes but appeal is rejected. It looks like they are reviewing live app apk for my appeal and issue isn’t addressed there, so, rejected appeal. Seems like I need to first upload app of live env then only this appeal will results in resuming account. But that isn’t feasible. Any advice here ?

For more detail: Suspension reason was that app dont have any 'publically accessible way for Privacy Policy'. I have added privacy policy into app in a way that user can access it without login or sign up.